# Errors when trying to validate password confirmation in React form with Joi

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, passwords, joi

I have been trying to create a schema where I can validate a 'confirm password' form field. When looking for a way to validate the field using Joi, I found most people use the Joi.any() function, but when I try to use it, I keep running into the same error. (This is the error I keep running into.) Here is my schema: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qJ9w.png)

```js
  schema = {
    username: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .label("Username"),
    password: Joi.string()
      .required()
      .min(5)
      .label("Password"),
    passwordconfirmation: Joi.any().equal(Joi.ref('password'))
      .required()
      .min(5)
      .label("Password"),
    dateofbirth: Joi.date()
      //.format(['YYYY-MM-DD', 'DD-MM-YYYY'])
      .required()
      .label("Date")
  };
```

And here are my import statements:

```js
import React from "react";
import Joi from "joi-browser";
import Form from "./Commons/form";
import './CSS/loginForm.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import JoiDate from "@hapi/joi-date";
import '@joi/date';
```

I'm not sure whether I'm using the wrong library or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's not

```
import Joi from "joi-browser";
```

It is:

```
import Joi from "joi";
```